# Measure event time (SystemModeler question)

Tags: system-modeler

How do I measure (and report to other parts of the system), the time that an event is true (in SystemModeler)?  There is a built-in block, Timer, that measures the time since an event became true.  I want the terminal value just before the event becomes false and don't see how to capture that since Timer clears when the event becomes false.  Is there another way to measure an event time and report it?  Ultimately, I plan to use this information as part of a controller.

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example?

Comment: Thank you for asking.  In SystemModeler, look up modelica://Modelica.StateGraph.Transition and go to FirstExample_Variant3.  That shows a state machine transitioning.  I'd like to have the value of timer.y available to other parts of the code.  Clearly the timer output is available since the example plots this variable.  I want the value just before it goes inactive.  How do I get that?  And while this example has the timer always returning the same value - in my case, it returns distinct values all the time.